# Html button doesn't redirect to link

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a button on html that when I press it to get redirected to http://example.com/mysite/?rand=1

What I tried so far is:

```
<form action="http://example.com/mysite/?rand=1">
    <div class="checkboxes" align="center">
        <input placeholder="TextArea" style="width: 296px; height: 30px;" type="text" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="x"><input type="checkbox" id="x" checked/><span> Just a checkbox 1 </span></label>
        <label for="y"><input type="checkbox" id="y" disabled/><span> Just a checkbox 2 </span></label>
        <button id="Button" type="submit">Press me</button>
</form>
```

I'm only redirected to http://example.com/mysite/?

I also tried with javascript like so:

```
<script "text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("Button").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "http://example.com/mysite/?rand=1";
        };
</script>

<form>
    <div class="checkboxes" align="center">
        <input placeholder="TextArea" style="width: 296px; height: 30px;" type="text" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="x"><input type="checkbox" id="x" checked/><span> Just a checkbox 1 </span></label>
        <label for="y"><input type="checkbox" id="y" disabled/><span> Just a checkbox 2 </span></label>
        <button id="Button">Press me</button>
</form>
```

The result is the same, I'm redirected to http://example.com/mysite/?

If I use other links to redirect, like google.com, etc, the redirect works just fine, but not with my actual site's link. The links works just fine if I open it in another tab

I'm not sure how to debug this, does anyone know any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: if you are using URL rewriting then its url rewriting issue...Plz check..Its redirecting on right address...but url rewriting truncates your query string.

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal I'm not sure if I understand, but if I open http://example.com/mysite/?rand=1 works just fine..

Comment: @Stefan, closing div is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<input>` elements need `name` attributes. The `name` is the parameter that ends up in the query string, while `id` is used for DOM manipulation and CSS.
Use a hidden `<input>` to add the `rand` parameter:

```
<input type="hidden" name=rand" value="1">
<input placeholder="TextArea" name="text" style="width: 296px; height: 30px;" type="text" autocomplete="off">
<label for="x"><input type="checkbox" name="x" id="x" checked/><span> Just a checkbox 1 </span></label>
<label for="y"><input type="checkbox" name="y" id="y" disabled/><span> Just a checkbox 2 </span></label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your html is not correct

here it is the corrected one

```
<form action="http://example.com/mysite/?rand=1">
    <div class="checkboxes" align="center">
        <input placeholder="TextArea" style="width: 296px; height: 30px;" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
        <label for="x">
            <input type="checkbox" id="x" checked="checked" /><span> Just a checkbox 1 </span>

        </label>
        <label for="y">
            <input type="checkbox" id="y" disabled="disabled" /><span> Just a checkbox 2 </span>

        </label>
        <button id="Button" type="submit">Press me</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JP8X7/1/)

Comment: @captainsac nothing i was just trying then i left it there